# Dictionary for loop

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, list-comprehension

Trying to create a for loop which reads in values from a SQL database put those values into a dictionary with the keys as the numbers.

Then from that dictionary use list comprehension to change those values into a list then eventually a dataframe but when I run the below code only 1 key is created and spits out only my first value. Not too sure why my for loop isn't looping correctly.

```
x = """SQL_script_1
  """

y = """SQLscript_2
"""

ting = [x, y]

def creator(SQLscript):
    cur = con.cursor()

    global dict0
    
    dict0 = {} 
    
    for i,j in zip(SQLscript,range(len(SQLscript))):
        cur.execute(i)

        ling =  cur.fetchall()

       # out = [item for t in ling for item in t]
        
        dict0[j] = ling[j]
        
        return dict0

        out1 = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]

     dict1 = {}
     for i,j in zip(out,out1):
         dict1[j] = i
```

Any help would be much appreciated?

Comment: All code written after a `return` statement is never executed. The function execution ends as soon as you return

Comment: Then dict0 should be populated with at least 2 keys and value pair but I'm only getting one ?

Comment: Why do you think dict0 should have 2 key/value pairs? It gets a single one on the line `dict0[j] = ling[j]` and then is returned immediately, which is why it only has 1